# Converting an InfoPath form to a PDF file

Tags: javascript, pdf, sharepoint-2010, pdf-generation, infopath2010

(I apologize for my English, but this is not my native language ^^)

I would like to have an opinion about converting InfoPath form of restitution to a PDF.
In summary I display a WebPart of list connected to a WebPat of InfoPath form vizialisation that I would like to perform an extraction to a PDF file.

My first solution is to make a custom action list items to generate PDF with iTextSharp library.
Problem: it’s cost in time and this developing three forms (InfoPath form editing, an InfoPath form  of reading and a PDF form generated by the code).

The second solution is to retrieve the contents of the WebPart in JavaScript to convert the HTML data into PDF, but that does not seem like very clean technique.

The last solution would be to create a custom page containing a XmlFormView encompassing the InfoPath form, on which it would be possible to perform an extraction with the addition of some code on a InfoPath button in the InfoPath form.
Outside, the Export method is not accessible in the dll Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.dll for SP forms. And I am also afraid of not being able to link my Web Part   of List View  on the InfoPath form.

In your opinion, what is the best solution? and what was the best way to resolve it?

Thank you in advance